# How many threads are allocated by default by actor system?

Tags: scala, akka

When I create an actor system

```
val simpleActorySystem = ActorSystem("SimpleActorSystem")
```

Can we determine, how many threads are allocated for the `SimpleActorSystem` by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [default dispatcher documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/dispatchers.html#default-dispatcher):

```
# warning: these values are not updated  regularly
# see documentation for most recent settings

# Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
parallelism-min = 2

# Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
parallelism-factor = 2.0

# Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
parallelism-max = 10
```